# Conditional Statements in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

A 'select' statement produce some sequence of data output like 'SL' 'CL''PL' etc as shown in below picture
[image]

If the data output is SL then it should be converted and displayed as 'Z', if its 'CL' the 'Q', if its 'PL' then 'R'

Is there any way to implement this

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CASE WHEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html)

```
select case when dbreed1 = 'SL' then 'Z'
            when dbreed1 = 'CL' then 'Q'
            when dbreed1 = 'PL' then 'R'
            else 'other'
       end dbreed1_mapped
```

You can also write your own function:

```
create or replace function map_breed(_input text) returns text as
$$
    select case when _input = 'SL' then 'Z'
                when _input = 'CL' then 'Q'
           end
$$
language sql;
```

And call it like this:

```
select map_breed('SL');
```

Comment: I could but is there any better way than that, like 'for' loop for the whole columns? so that no need to write for individual one

Comment: @Mr.Tananki I edited my answer so you only have to do the mapping once in the function

Comment: writing own function worked after struggling to handel the following error.

Comment: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "map_breed" line 2 at SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function map_breed(dbreed text) returns text as 
$$ 
   begin 
   select case when dbreed = 'SL' then 'Z' 
               when dbreed = 'CL' then 'Q' end into dbreed; 
   return dbreed;
   end; 
$$ language plpgsql; 

/*and call the function as*/
select map_breed('SL') as breed
```

Comment: A plain SQL function would be more efficient for this